# Getting 500 Error when trying to access localhost my_sql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a small page that I'm trying to building a journal with using PHP and My_SQL for both practice and recreation. I have a solid understanding of PHP but less so on My_SQL. Based on what I viewed it seemed that I can implement it almost like looking up a function and applying data to the corresponding areas. I tried doing the most basic thing and connect to my localhost server, but I cannot figure out why I am getting a 500 error. What is wrong with my server???

```
$servername = "http://127.0.0.1/";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "***";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else echo "Connected successfully";
```

`

Comment: `$servername = "http://127.0.0.1/";` just use the numbers `127.0.0.1` or use `localhost`

Comment: Although the `http://127.0.0.1/` is incorrect as already commented, that would not cause a 500 (fatal error). Make sure you enable error reporting, always when developing & testing code. At the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and the details of the 500 error will be clearer.

Comment: The error is now gone but something is clearly wrong as my slider on the page is gone. 
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /var/www/slider.php on line 347" There is no line 347 in the document but I can probably fix this problem somehow.

The main problem is that "Connected Successfully" isn't displaying in the browser as per the code.

Comment: `unexpected $end` probably indicates a missing closing `}` somewhere in slider.php.

Comment: Problem Solved, Thanks Guys!
How do I mark as resolved?